# How to approach these discrete problems?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

Struggling to understand this problem in discrete math.

*Lemma.*

> Let $N$ be an integer such that $N^2 = 3m$ for some integer $m$. Show that there is an integer $q$ such that $3q = N$.
> You may prove this by following the steps below.
>
> - Using the division algorithm we may write $N = 3q + r$ where $0 \le r < 3$. $\color{red}{\text{Explain why that we are done the proof if $r = 0$}}$.
> - Now argue by contradiction that $r = 0$. If $r > 0$, then $r = 1$ or $r = 2$ because $0 \le r < 3$.
>   First, show that $r = 1$ leads to a contradiction of the division algorithm using the fact that $N^2 = 3m$. $\color{red}{\text{You will use the $q$, $r$ in the division algorithm are unique}}$, that is there is only
>   $1$ choice for $q$, $r$ such that $N^2 = 3q + r$ with $0 \le r < 3$.
> - Assume that $r = 2$ and use the same strategy

Comment: Hi @bolokbee, welcome to MSE. Could you please use MathJax to format your equations? Here is a link to a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=2&tab=scoredesc#tab-top

Comment: Could you please point out exactly what you do not understand in this problem? Also, I have formatted your post using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) but some text (highlighted in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$) does not make sense to me. Please double-check that the text is indeed correct.

Comment: @an4s I wish i could tell you, that's why i don't understand the question. The only prompt missing in this question is "Use the division algorithm to solve the following lemma",

Comment: The problems with the red text appear to just be a language barrier. The author is not fluent in English and messed up the syntax a little. They should be "Explain why we are done with the proof if $r = 0$". The second red text should be "You will need the fact that the $q, r$ in the division algorithm are unique". There is also an error in the next line. It should still be $N = 3q + r$, not $N^2$.